# How should I respond to such a question?

Tags: questions

1. M: Amy doesn't speak Korean, right?
   W: *No*,* she does speak Korean. She has lived in Korea for three years!
2. M: Amy doesn't speak Korean, right?
   W: *Yes*, she does speak Korean. She has lived in Korea for three years!

Answer (score 0):

1 is the right answer. There is a statement and a question asking whether the statement that was just made is correct or wrong. The statement is wrong, as explained in the answer. So to break it down:
STATEMENT: Amy doesn't speak Korean.
QUESTION: (Am I) right?
ANSWER: No (you are not right)
EXPLANATION: She does speak Korean. She has lived in Korea for three years!

Comment: Thank you so much. Please check the tag question. Amy doesn't speak Korean, does she?  W: No/Yes,* she does speak Korean. She has lived in Korea for three years!- In this case, how should I respond? Still No? or Yes?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Ivy. Please add an objective source to substantiate your claim. As it stands this is just a very subjective take on the matter. Have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers.

Answer (score 0):

M: Amy doesn't speak Korean, right? W: Yes, she does speak Korean. She has lived in Korea for ...  This is the right answer, because we should say "she does speak or she does not speak" regardless of the questions.